# Docker not installing node_modules with yarn

Tags: node.js, ruby-on-rails, docker, yarnpkg

I am running a Ruby on Rails app with Webpacker using Yarn and trying to run this on Docker via Docker Compose. When I run `docker compose build` it looks like it runs successfully, but the node_modules folder is nowhere to be found and I can't use any node packages. I tried adding `- /app/node_modules` to the volumes as suggested in other posts but to no avail.

```
FROM ruby:3.0.0
RUN bundle config --global frozen 1

WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock ./
RUN bundle install


COPY . .

RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN npm install --global yarn
RUN yarn install
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    command: "rails server -b 0.0.0.0"
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - /app/node_modules
  db:
    image: "postgres:13"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
```

Comment: Have you tried `docker-compose up` and see what logs saying?

Comment: Mounting volumes over `/app` is hiding everything the Dockerfile does.  Delete the entire `volumes:` section of the `web` service.

Comment: The other weird thing is after I have the image running, I can run docker compose exec web yarn install and then that actually does add the node modules, but I need it to run on the build step

Answer (score 0):

Remove volumes from `web` service or mount only what you exactly need, not everything in the directory.
If you're mounting you're local directory, then it `overwrite` everything inside the container.

A good practice is to create `.dockerignore` file as well.
Put there what shouldn't be copied from host machine like `node_modules`

Comment: Isn't using volumes a two way sync? Unfortunately this didn't work